# Specify Git Rename after changes

Tags: git

Due to the tools I usually use, I often rename a file, and make changes to it, before getting ready to commit.

At this point, git no longer detects the file as a simple rename, because the file contents are different.

Is there a command I can use to specify that some file, is actually also a rename of another file, even though the contents appear different?

Comment: Did you use `git mv` to rename? `git status` should in this case tell you that you renamend and modified the file.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How does git detect similar files, for its rename detection?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7938582/how-does-git-detect-similar-files-for-its-rename-detection)

Comment: @Jan No, I'm usually renaming files through other tools, not git.  Hence why I was hoping there was a command so I could retroactively tell the server that a rename occurred that it didn't detect.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not in Git.  Git uses similarity-based heuristic ***rename detection*** (you might need to enable it for viewing changes: `git diff -M`, or `git config diff.renames true` to always use it (or `git diff -C` and `git config diff.renames copies` to also detect copies).  It detects renames on-the-fly.

It doesn't do **rename tracking**, and does not store information about renames anywhere.

---

That's assuming that you did not forget to include renamed file in the commit, i.e. you used `git mv <old> <new>`... which is just `mv <old> <new> && git add <new>`.

This means that if you have renamed file using other tools (e.g. IDE, filemanager, etc.), then you need to `git add` new file (after rename), and delete old file if it exists (`git rm` to remove it entirely, `git rm --cached` to keep it in the working directory).

Answer (score 4):

For git, you should never really rename and make file changes in the same commit. you should run a `git mv oldName newName` to ensure that git knows that it was a simple move of a file, then commit your changes.

Answer (score 0):

The safest way is to run `git mv old new` and commit the change (not just staging). Though this might break your build. And then make the new changes.

There is very nice blog and a link to discussion(rough) from git creator about this topic here https://coderwall.com/p/_csouq/renaming-and-changing-files-in-git-without-losing-history