# Where can I view the file associations with file hashes?

Tags: git

I know that git stores files as SHA-1 hashes, but it also tracks the names of files.

In a bare repository where can I see this information.

For example I can look at the files in objects like this:  Here is 4 files in my initial push under `objects/`

[image]

Comment: Git does not track filenames; https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Git-Objects

Comment: I've heard that but than how does it know when I change a file name than and push the file name change to my server ?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/7938582/3906760

Comment: File names are stored in tree objects, see the git internals link in @MrTux coment

Comment: I was looking for the tree objects in my git bare repo but could not find them.

Comment: not sure I understand the question do you want the files listed in the result of
`git whatchanged your-sha1 -1` ?

Comment: `tree object - lists the contents of the directory and specifies which file names are stored as which blobs.
` - this is take from git pro the book

Answer (score 0):

You can issue

```
git cat-file -p HEAD^{tree}
```

This lists the (root) tree of your latest commit. The third column represents the object id. The first two chars of it represent the folder name and the rest the filename for unpackaged objects in `.objects`. Blob are files and tree is a subtree (a subfolder, you can see it by issuing `git cat-file -p [OBJECTID]^{tree}` where `[OBJECTID]` is the charsequence of the third column.)

(when using Windows you might need to replace `^` with `^^`)

See https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Git-Objects for more information how Git stores files and objects.

Comment: `tree object - lists the contents of the directory and specifies which file names are stored as which blobs.
` - this is take from git pro the book