# Move files to root of git repo

Tags: git, git-bash

I need to move all files from folder "example" to the root of the git repo. I cannot figure out the command for it.
Can anybody help? 
Thanks

Comment: This could have been done in 10seconds by googleing `git how to move files`....

Comment: http://githowto.com/moving_files

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I move all git content one-level up in the folder hierarchy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7130850/how-can-i-move-all-git-content-one-level-up-in-the-folder-hierarchy)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
git mv example/* .
git commit -m "moved example/* to root"
```

Comment: Tried this already, but it gives the following:
fatal: bad source, source=example/*, destination=*

Comment: What's the output of `ls example | wc -l`? I get your output when "example" is empty and I try `git mv example/* .`.

Comment: Now I see what I did wrong. I typed the command to the windows terminal, not to the git bash terminal... I am getting older.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `git mv` command. Look at the commands and resulting output below. This was done in the ZShell, but should work on Bash and others.

```
/tmp/test
.:
total 4.0K
drwxrwxr-x 2 ray ray 4.0K Sep  2 03:22 example/

./example:
total 0
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ray ray 0 Sep  2 03:22 file1.txt
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ray ray 0 Sep  2 03:22 file2.txt
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ray ray 0 Sep  2 03:22 file3.txt
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ray ray 0 Sep  2 03:22 file4.txt
➜  test git:(master) git mv example/* .
➜  test git:(master) ✗ gst
On branch master
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

        renamed:    example/file1.txt -> file1.txt
        renamed:    example/file2.txt -> file2.txt
        renamed:    example/file3.txt -> file3.txt
        renamed:    example/file4.txt -> file4.txt

➜  test git:(master) ✗ ls -lR
.:
total 4
drwxrwxr-x 2 ray ray 4096 Sep  2 03:22 example
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ray ray    0 Sep  2 03:22 file1.txt
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ray ray    0 Sep  2 03:22 file2.txt
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ray ray    0 Sep  2 03:22 file3.txt
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ray ray    0 Sep  2 03:22 file4.txt

./example:
total 0
➜  test git:(master) ✗ git commit -m "Moved example/* to project root"
[master 1999275] Moved example/* to project root
 4 files changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 rename example/file1.txt => file1.txt (100%)
 rename example/file2.txt => file2.txt (100%)
 rename example/file3.txt => file3.txt (100%)
 rename example/file4.txt => file4.txt (100%)
➜  test git:(master)
```

Make sure that you're trying to move the *files* and not the directory, which could cause that error message:

```
/tmp/test
total 8.0K
drwxrwxr-x 2 ray ray 4.0K Sep  2 03:29 ex/
drwxrwxr-x 2 ray ray 4.0K Sep  2 03:22 example/
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ray ray    0 Sep  2 03:22 file1.txt
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ray ray    0 Sep  2 03:22 file2.txt
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ray ray    0 Sep  2 03:22 file3.txt
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ray ray    0 Sep  2 03:22 file4.txt
➜  test git:(master) git mv example ex
fatal: source directory is empty, source=example, destination=ex/example
```

Last, but not least, make sure the files within the directory are *already being tracked*. If you try to `git mv` files that have never been `git add`ed and/or `git commit`ed, then you'll also run into this error message.