# Local project and git repo not matching?

Tags: git, github

I have noticed that my git repo does not match mt local project structure?
Here is my git: https://github.com/BillyCharter87/Tech-O-Dex-API

Yet my local is al follows below:

[image]

I want my git repo to look like my local, essentially getting rid of the `inital` and `test` folders? Was my git init started in the wrong place or something?

Thanks.

Comment: What do you get when you run a `git status`?

Comment: `D:\Work\Tech-O-Dex-API>git status
On branch master
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

        deleted:    .travis.yml
        deleted:    CONTRIBUTING.adoc
        deleted:    Jenkinsfile
        deleted:    LICENSE.code.txt
        deleted:    LICENSE.writing.txt
        deleted:    README.adoc
        deleted:    run-on-pws.json
`

Comment: This lists the correct files that were deleted, but the do not reflect on the git repo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see from the path in the IDE your project only uses the sub directory `complete` instead of the whole repository. I guess that is OK, since that is where the project files and the pom.xml are located.

Not sure why the directory `initial` is there in the first place. It looks like a copy of the project, but maybe(?) not up to date with the contents of the `complete` directory. Check it. You may then want to delete either `initial` or `complete`.

If you are sure you want to remove the contents of the directories `initial` and `test` (as mentioned: check it), you can do the following in Git:

```
# remove both directories, intial and test
git rm -rf initial test
```

After that you can do a `git commit` to commit these changes.

The directory `complete` will still be there, however. If you want to move the contents of that directory up one level, you can do it as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19464714/6710751), which boils down to sonething like (untested):

```
git mv complete/* .
git rm complete
git add *
git commit
```

Comment: Ideally I'd like to remove both `initial` and `test` all together as I do not use them for anything.

Comment: OK, then do `git rm -rf initial test` in the repository's root directory as already mentioned above.

Comment: https://github.com/BillyCharter87/Tech-O-Dex-API Now my repo looks like this? Yet my local project structure looks/works perfect?

Comment: No, that will not work, you have removed too many files. Not only `initial` and `testing` are gone (as should be), but also the project files are gone. Assuming that [commit 1832d3d3d7642f5c1c1c08fac552f2218e4a8c2a](https://github.com/BillyCharter87/Tech-O-Dex-API/commit/1832d3d3d7642f5c1c1c08fac552f2218e4a8c2a) still contains all relevant files, you could do a `git checkout 1832d3d3d76 -- complete` to restore the files of the directory `complete`.

Comment: Locally on my machine it works fine, It's just not pushing the `.idea`, `.mvn`, `src` folders?

My git ignore is as follows:
*.sw?
.#*
*#
*~
.classpath
.project
.settings
bin
build
target
dependency-reduced-pom.xml
*.sublime-*
/scratch
.gradle
README.html
*.iml
.idea

Comment: Then add the `src` folder with `git add`. The `.idea` folder does not need to be added and also is listed in the `.gitignore` file. That is why it was not added - and thus not pushed.