# git move all content one level up, for all branches

Tags: git, git-filter-branch

I want to move all the content in a git repository one level up, and need this to apply for every branch I have. Literally, I have:

```
+--repo
+----+.git
+----+folder
+--------+ A
+--------+ B
```

And I want simply:

```
+--repo
+----+.git
+----+A
+----+B
```

This post [How can I move all git content one-level up in the folder hierarchy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7130850/how-can-i-move-all-git-content-one-level-up-in-the-folder-hierarchy) has an nice answer, suggesting to do:

```
git mv folder/* ./ -k
```

Now how do I do with all the branches? I can think of:

- do the `git mv` for master, then `git rebase` for all, on master
- do the `git mv` for all branches?

Is there an advantage of one over the other? I saw also some answers based on `git filter-branch --index-filter` (answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5408475/moving-a-git-repository-up-one-hierarchy-level/5408586)) but don;t understand how to apply it to my case.

Thanks!

Comment: You could move the folders, and then add those changes?

Comment: but would you do that for every branch, or for one then rebase? Thanks

Comment: Depends on the commit tree structure. It might make most sense to do it on each branch rather than relying on `filter-branch` or `rebase`.

Comment: I always had the .git and folder at the same level, and all branches were based on that structure, so it seems a "one for all" operation would make sense? What do you mean by *depends on the tree structure* exactly? Mind elaborating on that in a post? Thanks a lot!!

Comment: Do you understand what a commit tree is?

Comment: not deeply I guess! So if your answer answer could not assume good knowledge of the commit tree, would be great, thanks :-)

Comment: This will take a while, I’m not great at writing answers.

Comment: `git filter-branch --subdirectory-filter folder --tag-name-filter cat  -- --all` will rewrite your entire history,

Comment: It looks like you're not looking to rewrite the history, so `git mv` on `master`, and then rebase (or merge) of other branches is the most straightforward way.

Answer (score 8):

I would use the [new `git filter-repo`](https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo), which [does replace the old `git filter-branch` or BFG](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58251653/6309).

It comes with [many usage examples](https://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo/blob/docs/html/git-filter-repo.html#EXAMPLES), including path-based filtering, in order for you to move folder content to the top (assuming the top directory only includes folder)

```sh
cd /path/to/second/clone
git filter-repo --path-rename folder/:
```

By default, `git filter-repo` applies to all branches.

Comment: thanks! So yes, top directory has only `.git` and `folder`, does that still fit into your assumption of *top directory only includes folder*? Slightly confused about the path you indicate, would you not do it on the main clone? Or is it just to test first? thanks again!!

Comment: @Matifou You can test it on a separate local clone. The path rename is: "rename folder to /" (/ being the root folder of the repo).