# git mv not working on windows to move files to a parent folder

Tags: windows, git

I have tried every syntax I can think of but nothing has worked.

My repo all my files are in Files\MyFiles and I want to move them into the root of the repo.

The only command that has actually done anything without an error is

`git mv ./Files/MyFiles/ ./`

However all this did was move the MyFiles folder up one level. What I wanted to do was remove both of these folders so just the contents of MyFiles was in the root of the repo.

I have tried all kinds of stuff, adding wildcards, dots, changing the folder I'm in etc. but nothing has worked, I always get some variation of an error.

Is there a way to use this command correctly?

e.g.

```
C:\git\MyRepo [master ≡]> git mv ./Files/MyFiles/* ./ 
fatal: bad source, source=Files/MyFiles/*, destination=*
```

Comment: Not an answer to `Is there a way to use this command correctly?` but speaks something against simply doing it in the file browser? Anyway have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21581211/7111561): you can use the `-k` option to also move so far untracked files.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I move all git content one-level up in the folder hierarchy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7130850/how-can-i-move-all-git-content-one-level-up-in-the-folder-hierarchy)

Comment: Also note [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47872966/7111561) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22287013/7111561) both are addressing the windows command line in specific.

Answer (score 0):

Go to child folder and run ***for /f %f in ('dir /b') do git mv %f ../*** , it will move files from child folder parent folder