# move my root directories one level up in GitHub?

Tags: windows, git, github

I set up my Github directory the way that one extra folder contains the server folder.
is there a way to move my entire directory one level up in Github?

I tried "git mv repo.git/webapp/* repo.git/." with gitbash
it sends a fatal: bad source error.

thanks for your help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I move all git content one-level up in the folder hierarchy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7130850/how-can-i-move-all-git-content-one-level-up-in-the-folder-hierarchy)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+move+one+level+up